# Historical version of xeCJK package

Tags: packages, xecjk

I installed texlive on 11 Aug ,2017, and I accidentally updated the xeCJK package to the latest edition yesterday, now I need a xeCJK package that matches my version, could you please send me a link to download the historical version of the package? Many thanks!

Comment: What was your version and what is it now?

Comment: The [CTAN page](https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) gives links to the [home page](http://www.ctex.org/) of the package as well as to its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit).

Comment: Texlive has a backup system. If you didn't deactivate it you should  be able to return to the previously installed version with tlmgr.

Comment: @AndréC Time: 2017/08/11 and 2018/04/30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CTAN page gives links to the html page of the package as well as to its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/tree/xeCJK-v3.7.1/xeCJK).

#### 1. This is the repository:

click on the `branch Master` button:

[image: repository]

#### 2. You have access to previous versions

**tag tab**, here `xeCJK-v3.5.0` *(Latest commit on 7 Aug 2017)* :

[image]

#### 3. Get the code:

Just click on the **code tab** at the top left 
[image: version 3.5.0]

#### Download:

the download button will appear on the right.

[image: download]

If you have not been able to do it alone, you must [arrive here](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/tree/xeCJK-v3.5.0), where by clicking on the download button, you can download the old version., here

```
ctex-kit-xeCJK-v3.5.0.zip
```